# Change htaccess File to Redirect to HTTPS?

Tags: .htaccess, https

I would like *everyone* accessing http://my-domain.com.au or http://www.my-domain.com.au to automatically be re-directed to https://www.my-domain.com.au on my (shared web hosting) domain, however I have not yet had any luck in accomplishing this.

First I tried to create a re-direct in cPanel, however this does not seem to have had any effect at all.

Then I contacted my host, who indicated that I would need to edit my "htaccess" file...

The original "htaccess" file for this domain contains:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteOptions inherit

AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile "/home/CPANEL LOGIN USERNAME/.htpasswds/public_html/passwd"
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-domain\.com\.au$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.my-domain\.com\.au$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.my-domain\.com\.au\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

I tried to replace this with (from StackExchange):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-domain\.com.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.my-domain.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]

# check if https if off and check if the requested uri ends with login
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} login$
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

And:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-domain\.com\.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.my-domain.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]

# check if https if off and check if the requested uri ends with login
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} login$
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

However thus far, none of those revisions to the "htaccess" file have had any effect...

Any help in achieving my goal would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Where did the "original `.htaccess` file" come from? That implies there is a parent config that needs to be "inherited"? Also that you might be behind some kind of SSL proxy? (Unless of course all that was an attempt to get this redirect to work?) Your second two code dumps seem to be the same (except for backslash-escape - which doesn't really make any difference)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone on another website helped me, and the answer was to edit the "htaccess" file so it had only the following contents:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The example.com section is where you put your website URL.

Answer (score 1):

> However thus far, none of those revisions to the "htaccess" file have had any effect...

No effect at all? Even changing it to something simple, such as redirecting all traffic to a single page?

If that's the case, then you should first confirm that .htaccess contains "AllowOverride All". The default is "AllowOverride None" which means the server will completely ignore the .htaccess file.

> ```
> # check if https if off and check if the requested uri ends with login
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} login$
> RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
> ```

This rewrite rule will only apply to URIs ending with the word "login". If you're intending to apply this to all pages and all visitors, you should remove the second condition.

Answer (score 1):

> First I tried to create a re-direct in cPanel, however this does not seem to have had any effect at all.

You can't actually do HTTP to HTTPS redirects using the cPanel interface, so it's quite possible that anything you entered would have simply failed to match. However, cPanel also places the redirect directives at the end of the `.htaccess` file (as per the [documentation](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/74Docs/Redirects#)), which is often the wrong place for external redirects and can also account for the redirect "not doing anything".

The cPanel redirects interface is very limited.